# How do i extract a row of a dataframe to another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe which consists of a column which will have information like "car,motorbike,person,pot" I want to copy those specific rows having "car" in the name column to another empty dataframe.
The code is this

```
  detections=model(image)
  l=detections.pandas().xyxy[0]
  col=list(l.columns)
  df = pd.DataFrame(columns= col)
  row=l.loc[(df['name'] == 'car'),l.columns]
  print(row)
```

The dataframe looks like this

[image: dataframe]

The error which my google colab is showing me is this

**IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).**

Please help.

Comment: Add part or entire dataframe like this we can try to reproduce what you want in our own IDE. You can copy/paste here the result of "df.to_dict".

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create the dataframe with columns beforehand. Just use this

```
df = l[l['name'] == 'car']
```

Comment: Empty DataFrame
Columns: [xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax, confidence, class, name]
Index: []

it prints that df is empty

Comment: then maybe show us the l dataframe

Comment: or maybe a link to your colab

Comment: i have uploaded the pic of the dataframe. it has columns of x_min,y_min and all. Tell me if you cant see it, I'll edit it.

Comment: type this line and show us the result l.name.value_counts()